# Typescript class inheritance

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing here. I need to create a base class, so that my controls can inherit from it. So I did this base class:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

export class FormBaseComponent  {
  constructor(
    protected location: Location
  ) {}

  goBack() {
    alert('back');
    this.location.back();
  }

}
```

and a class that inherit from it:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder
} from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService } from 'app/shared/services/user/user.service';
import { User } from 'app/models/authentication/user';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { FormBaseComponent } from 'app/shared/components/form-base.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-account',
  templateUrl: './my-account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-account.component.scss']
})
export class MyAccountComponent extends FormBaseComponent implements OnInit  {
  formEdit = this.fb.group(User.formGroup());

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private userServices: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    location: Location
  ) {
    super(location);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userServices.getCurrentUser().subscribe( x => {
      this.formEdit.patchValue(x);
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.userServices.update(this.formEdit.getRawValue()).subscribe( x => {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
  }

}
```

Is it correctly to declare this "location" parameter in the constructor like this?

```
  location: Location
) {
  super(location);
}
```

BTW, this code works as expected.

Comment: Yes, that is how you inherit in typescript. Refer this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: @dileepkumarjami, yes! I was a bit confused but now I got the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` is used to send arguments to the base class constructor from the derived class. If this was your confusion, it is the right way.

(perhaps this is the only use for the `super` keyword!)

Also, if you dont give a modifier like `public` or `private` you can take arguments that do not form a part of the given class. So your code is indeed the way it is supposed to work.

essentially the `modifier` creates a new class element `classVar` and assigns the argument `classVar` supplied to constructor to `this.classVar`
ie,

```
class Sample {
    classVar: number;
    constructor(classVar : number) {
         this.classVar = classVar
    }
```

would be equivalent to

```
class Sample {
    constructor(public classVar : number) {
    }
```